# Can't find Google App Maker in list of Additional Google services

Tags: google-app-maker

I am trying to turn on Google App Maker for our G-Suite business. Within the Google admin console, I navigate to Apps then Additional Google services. In the list I don't see a row for Google App Maker.

[image]

Is App Maker limited release or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure your G Suite level is really Business and not Basic? App Maker is only available in Business and Enterprise pricing plans.

Answer (score 1):

App Maker is already available for all G Suite Business and Enterprise editions. It's listed as **App Maker** and not *Google App Maker*, so it should be at the top of the **Additional Google Services** page if you are sorting in ascending order.

It should be default ON so try to access at [appmaker.google.com](http://appmaker.google.com)

If you just upgraded to G Suite Business, allow at least 24 h for all new services to become available. If you still can't find App Maker, [contact support.](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213?hl=en)